# Apache Beam GenerateSequence does not emit elements at specified rates

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am experimenting with Apache Beam, and tried to use the GenerateSequence PTransform as a simple way to generate an unbounded, streaming data source.

The GenerateSequence class provides the method `withRate(long numElements, Duration periodLength)`, which to my understanding, controls the rate of elements produced per period as well as the duration of the period. To my surprise, the rate at which the elements were produced was not consistent with the provided description.

For example, I tried to use the following snippet of code:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
Duration runtimeDuration = Duration.standardSeconds(20L);
Duration periodDuration = Duration.standardSeconds(1L);
PCollection<String> generated_seq = p.apply("Get Sequence",
        GenerateSequence.from(1)
                .withMaxReadTime(runtimeDuration)
                .withRate(1, periodDuration))
        .apply("Test sequence generation", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long,String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element Long in, OutputReceiver<String> out){
                long userId = in % 5; //simulate events from 5 users
                Instant timestamp = Instant.now();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.SSSzZ").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT"));
                System.out.println(in + " => UserId:" + userId + "|Timestamp: " + timestamp.toString(fmt));
                out.outputWithTimestamp(Long.toString(userId), timestamp);
            }
        }));
```

The pipeline generated the resulting sequence:

```
5 => UserId:0|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.361GMT+0000
14 => UserId:4|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.446GMT+0000
6 => UserId:1|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.450GMT+0000
12 => UserId:2|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.452GMT+0000
7 => UserId:2|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.456GMT+0000
9 => UserId:4|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.459GMT+0000
13 => UserId:3|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.461GMT+0000
1 => UserId:1|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.463GMT+0000
2 => UserId:2|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.465GMT+0000
16 => UserId:1|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.468GMT+0000
10 => UserId:0|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.469GMT+0000
8 => UserId:3|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.471GMT+0000
15 => UserId:0|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.474GMT+0000
4 => UserId:4|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.476GMT+0000
17 => UserId:2|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.478GMT+0000
11 => UserId:1|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-25.488GMT+0000
3 => UserId:3|Timestamp: 2021-03-08 21-20-37.613GMT+0000
```

As observed above, the majority of elements were generated within the **same second** despite specifying  `withRate(1, periodDuration)`; that is, specifying that at most 1 element should be generated in a period of 1 second

I have tried to dig into the SDK code to understand and hopefully resolve the reason for this behavior but I could not identify its cause. Thus, is there a way to either resolve this issue, or are there any similar PTransforms that can emulate an unbounded, streaming source?

Comment: Can you add the variables runtimeDuration and periodDuration to your code sample?

Comment: Hi @Iñigo, I have updated my code sample to include the full snippet by which the output is generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

This is likely caused by a quirk in the `GenerateSequence` transform that isn't really explained by the documentation. Specifically, the way the underlying source used to generate the numbers ([`CountingSource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.28.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/CountingSource.java)) works is that if it runs out of elements to emit, there is a brief wait before the source is checked again. If this wait time is greater than the period duration, then multiple elements may be queued up next time the source is checked, and the source will advance through them rapidly.

So in your example, what is likely happening is that the source starts, and does not emit any elements yet because the period of one second hasn't passed. It is checked again several seconds later, at which point it rapidly emits all elements that should have been emitted in that time period, until it runs out and then waits again. This can be seen with the last element in your example, which was emitted 12 seconds after the previous one. Expanding the runtime duration is a good way to see this in action; You will likely see multiple batches of elements being emitted.

### Timestamps

The behavior described above works perfectly if all you need are the raw numbers being generated periodically. However if you are using `GenerateSequence` to test a pipeline that depends on timestamps, you will want to set a custom [TimestampFn](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/GenerateSequence.html#withTimestampFn-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-) to set the timestamps for each emitted element. The [default TimestampFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.28.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/CountingSource.java#L136) in the source may be a good example to use. A very simple one that might work for you is to set the timestamp to match the value of the element.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, thanks for the extensive answer. I tried to use the `withTimestampFn()` of the `GenerateSequence` to compensate for the quirk, but wasn't able to. In the meantime, I have discovered the `TestStream` class, which is more intuitive to use. I will be accepting this answer as it elaborates on the peculiarities of the `GenerateSequence`